# Get the element on its own tootip click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am having a doubt in jquery ui tooltip,

When i click on a tooltip, i want the element, which the tooltip belongs to,

### What i did was

```
    $(".sample").tooltip({
           content: function () {
                return $(this).prop('title');
            },
        show: null, 
        position: {
            my: "center bottom-20",
            at: "center top",
            using: function( position, feedback ) {
              $( this ).css( position );
              $( "<div>" )
                .addClass( "arrow" )
                .addClass( feedback.vertical )
                .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
                .appendTo( this );
            }
          },
        close: function (event, ui) {

            ui.tooltip.hover(

            function () {
                $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
            },

            function () {
                $(this).fadeOut("400", function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                })
            });
            ui.tooltip.click(function(e){
                $(this).parent();
            });
        }
    });
```

When i took the parent inside the click function of ui.tooltip.click, its showing the body,

### Element is like this

```
<span title="follow" class="sample"></span>
```

When i hover this, I want the span with class "sample" as result

Thanks

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi thanks, I already tried, and mentioned in question, it will give the result as the body Div

Comment: Your selector is for `.follow`, your class is `sample`

Comment: @Pete: Ya I am sorry, It was sample, there is a mistake in question, I am using class sample only and I am not getting it

Comment: And with $( e.target ) in place of $(this) ?

Comment: @lateek35 : thanks , But issue not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$(e.originalEvent.target)`:

```
close: function (event, ui) {
    var original = $(event.originalEvent.target);
    ui.tooltip.hover(

    function () {
        $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
    },

    function () {
        $(this).fadeOut("400", function () {
            $(this).remove();
        })
    });

    ui.tooltip.click(function () {
        console.log(original.text())
    });
}
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/fmx5atko/4/)

Comment: One thing is correct that it is append not in it, But it appends in body only, not as a sibling

Comment: ah, I was using an old version of ui.  Let me update it and see

Comment: In click of tooltip it returns this <div class="ui-tooltip-content">Follow</div>

Comment: I want the span with class sample as result, (which the clicked tooltip belongs to)

Comment: Sorry, bad testing on my part, put it in the wrong place, updated again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use `$(event.currentTarget)` (event refers to close's attributes function)

```
close: function (event, ui) {

        ui.tooltip.hover(

        function () {
            $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
        },

        function () {
            $(this).fadeOut("400", function () {
                $(this).remove();
            })
        });
        ui.tooltip.click(function(e){
            console.log($(event.currentTarget));
        });
}
```

The fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zvsjz6a0/